# Remove everything before the first / in a field and output it

Tags: mysql

I have data in a MySQL table like this:

```
us/books/fiction
```

In MySQL alone, during the select, is it possible to remove what's before the first `/` so that the final data that's outputted looks like this:

```
books/fiction
```

I have searched but could not find any function in MySQL that could do this.

**I tried this, but it leaves the / before. I'm trying to do it without the /**

```
select substring(url, instr(url, '/')) from myTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add +1, to also get rid of that / in your substring:

```
select substring(url, instr(url, '/') + 1) from myTable;
```